# How should I implement a circular buffer of debug messages?

Tags: android, debugging

I am using [ACRA](http://www.google.fr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CGYQFjAA&url=http://code.google.com/p/acra/&ei=gJvbT6z8ENC08QOP9LGZCw&usg=AFQjCNF1L9fawVNYyKuqqIa7q22TBcL08w&sig2=hJhk6UmWVv95dmqSYlYPXQ) as a crash and error reporting lib in my Android app.

It offers an option to send the content of LogCat along with the error reports, but I do not wish to use this feature as it requires a READ_LOGS permission, that may represent a threat to some users.

I am essentially interested in sending my own application debug logs along with the error reports I send using ACRA. Of course there needs to be a maximum size of this debug history (e.g. only the last 20 messages would be saved and sent). And I could store messages by simply calling something like `storeLog("User has clicked button 1")`.

To achieve this, I would need either:

- a circular buffer, storing (Timestamp t, String message) pairs. Drawback of this option: need to pass this buffer between classes, loss of history on application exit (unless if I save it to a file or SharedPreferences)
- a rolling file.

Which option is to be preferred, and how can it be implemented (especially the "rolling" behavior) ?